# Django best practices replacing old files with file uploads

Tags: django, django-forms

In summary, what I'm trying to accomplish here is:

- To perform transformation over uploaded files' names for organization and security's sake
- Not to keep old files in storage forever

Let's say that you have a `Company` model which has a logo. Something like

```
class Company(models.Model):
  name = ...
  logo = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, since I'm a bit paranoid and I don't really like the fact that uploaded files get the name given by the (potentially evil) user, I add a `upload_to` parameter that points to a function that's something like

```
def logo_getfilename(instance, filename):
  extension = ... # get just the original extension from the file
  return 'logos/' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + extension
```

Ok, so now only the view is missing!

```
def company_edit(request, ...):
  company = ... # get the company and stuff

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CompanyAdminForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=company)
    last_file_path = None
    if not company.logo is None:
      last_file_path = company.logo.path
    # ^^ after calling is_valid(), file_path gets changed to
    # the would-be-default-behavior
    if form.is_valid():
      # first we write the new file
      form.save()
      # now we remove the old one
      os.unlink(last_file_path)
```

Although this is currently working, I'm not really comfortable with it because

- I'm using `os.unlink()` instead of `FieldFile.delete()` which seems wrong
- I'm assuming a local filesystem storage
- I'm still not doing anything against naming collisions (they may still happen)
- I'm disregarding multiple chunks and assuming that `form.save()` will deal with everything
- I'm not considering transactional behavior (previous file should be deleted only after the `.save()` model changes are commited to the database
- I feel there are some problems there I don't even know about

So to acheive these simple (and not as uncommon as that) goals, what would be your recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a random username, why not use the primary key for the Company? When they upload a new file, just have it overwrite the existing one (which I think it will do automatically as long as you change the file name before you save). This should remove your need to do `os.unlink` and (maybe) stop your transactional worries.